# Cassandra: high CPU usage and unresponsive DB, probably due to a stuck secondary index building - how to stop the index building process?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, secondary-indexes

In a single-node installation of Cassandra 3.7 on a VM running Debian, I have a table with about 20 million rows. In order to be able to select the data that was inserted during the last few days, I used Datastax DevCenter 1.6.0 to execute a statement to create an secondary index on a column containing the insertion date:

```
CREATE INDEX srsdata_datetimeinserted ON ccp.srsdata(datetimeinserted);
```

The statement itself ran quickly, and then, as I understand it, the index creation process started in hte background, with a close-to 100% CPU load on one of the cores. The problem is, this CPU load has been high now for over 24 hours and **starts again even after multiple restarts of the virtual machine**.

In order to check the index creation process, I have run

```
nodetool compactionstats
```

but almost from the beginning it seems to have stuck at 5.78% and hasn't changed at all during the last 24 hours:

```
pending tasks: 1
- ccp.srsdata: 1

id                                   compaction type       keyspace table   completed total    unit  progress
2616e5d0-c217-11e6-bbed-073889a74ba2 Secondary index build ccp      srsdata 655814    11350989 bytes 5.78%
Active compaction remaining time :   0h00m00s
```

I can SELECT from tables but not INSERT data, not even into other tables, I then get

```
"Cassandra timeout during write query at consistency ONE 
(1 replica were required but only 0 acknowledged the write)"
```

If I try to drop the index,

```
DROP INDEX srsdata_datetimeinserted;
```

I get

```
"Timed out waiting for server respones".
```

I have tried to stop the index building using

```
nodetool stop INDEX_BUILD
```

but it doesn't make any difference.

What can I do to stop and maybe restart the index creation? Or is there some other stuff running that I haven't though about?

**Update 2017-01-12**

I never got the index creation process to stop, so I ended up restoring the virtual server from a backup taken prior to creating the index.

I also found out about the new SASI indexes introduced in Cassandra 3.4 (http://www.doanduyhai.com/blog/?p=2058), and especially the SPARSE indexing mode is made for storing close-to-unique data such as millisecond timestamps. In fact, a maximum of 5 identical values is allowed. So I creataed a SASI index using

```
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX srsdata_datetimeinserted ON ccp.srsdata (datetimeinserted) USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex' WITH OPTIONS = { 'mode': 'SPARSE' };
```

The creation took about 20 minutes and seems to work fine, now I can make queries like

```
select * from ccp.srsdata where datetimeinserted >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00+0000' AND datetimeinserted < '2017-01-01 15:00:00+0000';
```

Comment: I'd try modeling your table to *not* use a secondary index.  And secondary indexes on high-cardinality columns (like date time) are an anti-pattern.  Even if this index finished building, your queries on it would perform very badly.

Comment: I'm aware of that it is not a good pattern, but it would be a query that would run seldom, once in a few weeks or so, and I would really like to avoid creating and maintaining a separate table just for this query. I don't really need to query by exact timestamp on millisecond level, so I guess if I had a date column (YYYY-MM-DD) that I could index would be a better option with significantly less cardinality?